# Why is arithmetic + preferred over textual one?

Tags: sql-server

If I run

```
select '1' + '1'
```

the result is 11, since I have added a text to another one.

If I run

```
select 1 + '1'
```

the result is 2. I assume the arithmetic operator is chosen over the concatenator because of the type of the first operand. If my reasoning was valid, then the result of

```
select '1' + 1
```

would be 11. But instead, it is 2. So, it seems that the operator + is tried to be used as an arithmetic operator and if neither of the operands is arithmetic, then goes on to the next operator. If that is true, that would explain why did I get the error of

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'customer_' to data type
>   int.

instead of `customer_<somenumber>` when I ran a `select and had 'customer_' + <somenumber>`.

Long story short: I think I observed that arithmetic `+` is preferred over its meaning of concatenation at SQL Server. Am I right? If so, is there an official reason of this behavior?

Comment: because of [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're running into is a matter of [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). SQL Server looks to character data types **after** numerics. So regardless of the ordering of your operands (`1 + '1'` vs `'1' + 1`), it's attempting to convert your types to numerics, and succeeding.

The same happens with your second attempt - it's trying to convert the string `customer_` to an integer because you're using an arithmetic operator along with an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer confirmed my assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the precedence is arithmetic first when compared to concatenation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

Your error, as you know, is because the it won't implicitly attempt to convert INT to VARCHAR